# Do all finite sets have the Bolzano-Weierstrass property?

Tags: real-analysis

The definition we have for Bolzano-Weierstrass is that a subset $S$ of a metric space has the Bolzano-Weierstrass property if every infinite subset of $S$ has a limit point in $S$.

Since a finite set has no infinite subsets, does that mean it has the Bolzano-Weierstrass property since it doesn't fail the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your definition is accurate, then yes, all finite sets have the Bolzano-Weierstrass property.

Comment: Do you know if our definition is accurate (equivalent to the standard definition of the Bolzano-Weierstrass property)?

Comment: After thinking about it briefly, I believe it is.

Answer (score 3):

Your statement of the Bolzano-Weierstrass property matches the one I have always seen, and yes, it is (vacuously) true for finite sets.

One way to see that this "should" be the case is to note that a major reason for considering the B-W property is the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem:

> A subset of a metric space has the Bolzano-Weierstrass property if and only if it is compact.

Finite sets are compact, so if the B-W property were not phrased in such a way as to include all finite sets, the B-W theorem as stated above would not be true.